# WebGL: Alpha channel from transparent pixels drawn over solid background leak into canvas buffer

Tags: canvas, webgl

Fairly new to WebGL, though I've been dabbling in it for a few months. I just encountered an issue with trying to blend transparent pixels over an already opaque background in my WebGL canvas buffer.

### Question

How do I draw the second rectangle so that it blends with the solid grey but it's alpha doesn't leak through to the canvas buffer? I do not want to set `alpha` to false on the WebGL context because my app may require things from behind to render.

### Scenario

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foxtrotwhiskey9/pygc4oLv/53/)

1. A WebGL canvas element exists with a blue (#0000ff) background CSS style on it
2. Solid light gray rectangle is drawn covering the entire canvas using a simple color shader
3. 50% transparent red rectangle is drawn over it using the same shader

The blending mode is set to:

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

#### Expected Result

[image: Grey rectangle with smaller dull red rectangle in the middle]

#### Actual Result:

[image: Grey rectangle with smaller pink rectangle in the middle]

### Problem

Alpha transparency from the red rectangle leaks through to the canvas, causing the blue background color of the canvas to be blended with the red color forming a hot pink.

- Try changing the background color of the canvas in my fiddle to see this in action

I've tried many blending mode combinations and I can't get one that works exactly how I want it. I feel like I want a blending mode that does the alpha blending but ensures the pixels drawn have a fully opaque alpha, but [there doesn't seem to be one that would ensure that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc)

Answer (score 1):

By default `premultipliedAlpha` is enabled. You have 2 options. Either you deactivate `premultipliedAlpha`:

```js
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {
  alpha: true,
  premultipliedAlpha: false 
});
```

or you change the blending function:

```js
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also see [WebGL and Alpha](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer! Your second solution seems to work well for my example, however the first one does not. Setting `premultipliedAlpha` to false does not result in the expected result. Anything I might be missing with it?